# Textview not showing complete text on Phone.linear layout

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

i have linear layout.inside there is textview.which sometiomes contains large information.
on pc if run application with emulator it works fine but on phone whole text is not showing.
left sided text is gone,cant c it,n only 1 line it is showing.
i think text wrapping is not working.

```
     android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

android:ellipsize="end"
android:ellipsize="marquee"

i tired this but not working

plz urgent help needed

Comment: Could you show us the layout with the textview in it for clarity?

Comment: remove width from wrap content and set it using you preferred size in dp

Answer (score 4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:id="@+id/Text1"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Try this...

You do not need to scroll your screen when using this code.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the TextView in ScollView ie:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"> 
        <TextView android:id="@+id/about_detail"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@color/white"/>
    </ScrollView>     
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this works\